# Migrate org.joda.time.Duration to java.time.Duration

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I want to migrate this java based on joda library to java.time

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Duration;
import org.joda.time.Instant;

private DateTime createdDate;
private Duration executionTime;
private Instant requestTime;


  public void startTimerProcess() {
    this.requestTime = Instant.now();
  }

  public void endTimerProcess() {
    this.executionTime = new Duration(requestTime, Instant.now());
  }
```

I tried this:

```
import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

private OffsetDateTime createdDate;
private Duration executionTime;
private Instant requestTime;


  public void startTimerProcess() {
    this.requestTime = Instant.now();
  }

  public void endTimerProcess() {
    this.executionTime = Duration.of(requestTime.toEpochMilli(), Instant.now());
  }
```

For the line `Duration.of` I get error:

```
Required type: TemporalUnit
Provided: Instant
```

Can you guide me what is the proper way to implement his migration, please?

Comment: Maybe useful since you are migrating joda to java time, this is my repository which provide some of the API conversion https://github.com/samabcde/migrate-joda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the duration *between* two instants, then you are looking for [`Duration#between(Instant, Instant)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-):

```
public void endTimerProcess() {
  this.executionTime = Duration.between(requestTime, Instant.now());
}
```